# Select from one DB and insert in another DB

Tags: oracle

I need a sql query in which

Select from DB1 and insert into DB2 in one single query

Example:
DB1
Select username,account_status from dba_users;

DB2
Insert into table User_id

Comment: DB link can't be used bcoz of company policy and security reasons.

Comment: You don't need a query for this - a query requires a DB link. Since you can't use one, you need something else. Export query results to a file, transfer the file, import on the other server.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You have to create a database link (this should probably be done by a DBA). Once that is in place, you can select from the other database and write a statement like this:</strike>

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * from MyTable@DB2
```

[Edit]

You can't without a database link.